# Does Windows Firewall need to be on to enable PowerShell remoting on Windows 2008/2012 servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Does Windows Firewall need to be on to enable PowerShell remoting on Windows 2008/2012 servers? That is, if the Windows Firewall on a 2008/2008 R2/2012 R2 server is turned off can PowerShell remoting be enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either have Windows Firewall "Off", create an exception, or execute the enable-psremoting which auto-builds your ACL.  If you disable Windows Firewall completely (service level disable), this actually can cause some issues.

It should work pretty easily though with Firewall enabled for Domain.

The command to enable-psremoting will actually create a filrewall exception for WS-Management and this is an easier way to go, especially if calling into Microsoft Premier service for any issues down the road.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx

Comment: And I just tested it on a scratch server by turning the Windows Firewall "off" and remotely enabling remoting with psexec.

Comment: We used to turn off Windows Firewall for most systems because it was easier but compliance forced us to turn it back on a year or so later, so that powershell command to enable it saved us some heartache.